# How to get a large pool of data in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new in **Vue.js** ecosystem and need some advise.

When user call specific URL from client side, backend (`Node.js`) return huge datapool in a stream mode. In backend application I use `JSONStream` package for that task. Backend return me huge datapool by pieces. Now in client side I am tring to receive that data in stream mode.

I tried `axios` package but it waits for the whole data pool. I have to get the data in batches. Can someone advice or show by little example how I can make it?!

Answer (score 4):

It will be surely a very poor database design. You will only need to send the least and only required data for each client side view or module. So that you will get your application working smoothly on both ends.

Sending thousands or millions of data from the server and receiving them from the client is really awkward. Thus, I would suggest you to give a re-look in the backend to try allowing data as per the requirement only.

View is just a showcase, and should not be used as storecase!

Comment: Let me try to explain you the situation. In my case that huge datapool is a monthly data of whole country which I need to show in google map. So I can't use pagination or lazy loading. It's now my case. I need all that data. I cannot reduce their number in backend. I thought that it would be better to show geo-objects on the map as the data is received in parts. Do you have any other ideas my friend?

Comment: It matters how huge the data is. You may load the data in different  phases like on first load, on click, etc.

Comment: Database return ~ 200 000 rows. You can assume that each row is an geo-object.

Comment: What about data to load on zooming to location of map?

Comment: I assure you that it's more difficult. The reason is that my geo objects are polygons. What do you think about `websocket`? Can I use it for my main task?

Comment: Whatever you use doesn't matter ui should not load huge data at once.

Comment: You are right. I don't want to load all data. I try to load data in pieces. Let me know if you have any other ideas.